# "READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" not showing in android manifest and MainActivity

Tags: java, android-studio, android-manifest, android-permissions, android-13

I am making a webview app where I need to access images from the file. According to the recent update of android 13, the apps targeting SDK 33 have to use  instead of <uses-permission **android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>**. But in my manifest, the <uses-permission **android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>** is not working.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7K8S3.png)

Besides, in mainActivity, when I am requesting permission from the manifest **Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES**, it is showing error. It is showing cannot ressolve symbol error.

[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7K8S3.png)